# Use a Named Credential with API key?

Tags: api, callout, security, authentication, namedcredentials

I want to be able to make callouts to JotForm, but they do not support OAuth and username/password is insufficient for their API. [Here are their docs](https://api.jotform.com/docs/#authentication); for reference, here are the 3 auth options:

> 1. Authenticate with Query Parameters
> 2. Authenticate with HTTP Headers
> 3. Authenticate with Javascript SDK

Basically, they provide an API Key and want me to include an apikey parameter in the header. I don't want to hard code it, I don't want to store it as plain text in custom settings/metadata, and this isn't a managed package. Is there any way to securely store/authenticate from Salesforce, ideally using a Named Credential?

I'd love to be able to just have a Named Credential that is just a securely stored, obscured API Key...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well... sort of. The only two officially supported methods are by Basic Authentication and OAuth tokens. That site uses a non-standard API design, so it can't *directly* benefit from using a Named Credential. "But wait," I hear you say, "you didn't say it wasn't possible." And for that, you'd be correct. Here's what we can do to work within this system's design.

First, go to the New Named Credential screen. Specify the base endpoint ("http://api.jotform.com/"), set the Identity Type to "Named Principle," choose Authentication Protocol "Password Authentication," specify any random user name ("anonymous" should work), and type in the API key as your password. Uncheck "Generate Authorization Header" and check "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header", then save this Named Credential.

Now, in your code, you can specify the API key using a merge field:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('callout:jotform/user');
req.setHeader('APIKEY', '{!$Credential.Password}');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

Comment: This is so simple, yet so brilliant! Thank you - confirmed working! (Salesforce really should formalize this hack in some way. Had it not been for you, I probably would have broken down and stored it in a metadata record...)

Comment: @Mike Salesforce can do a lot more than it gives credit for in the documentation. As long as I've been doing this, I'm usually inventing new ways to do things that aren't in the documentation.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks for the great info, by chance, will you say that this approach would be considered secure enough for a security review process?

Comment: @Joca As as non-ISV, I have no idea. The ISVforce guide suggests it is, but you'll ultimately need to ask the Partner Support team for a definitive answer.

Comment: Agree, I'll check with partner support then, thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox Can I use Named Credentials if the API I'm trying to make callouts to requires a username, password  **and** an additional access token?

Comment: @KaiTribble No, you only get two fields to use. If you need *more* than that, you definitely need to look at custom settings/custom metadata. NC was only meant to support Basic and OAuth2 connections; a non-standard header option was viable because there was only one value. If you need more than 2, then you'll have to use custom metadata or another method.

Comment: As of now, it seems like they've introduced some sort of validation when creating named credential with "Password Authentication". Now it is required to use 'https://' in url: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_security_named_credentials_scheme_enforcement.htm

Comment: And using https (i.e. ssl) requires to have signed ceritificate installed on that external server with api exposed (self-signed ones wouldn't work, moreover there is a whitelist of authorities which are trusted to issue such certificate). Cause of all these troubles we decided to go with custom settings to hold api key.

Comment: Just a heads up that you actually use $Credential, not the API name of your named credential. I tried {!$My_Named_Credential.Password} with, of course, no luck.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I am trying to do the same thing for Google Direction API, but getting error "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. "   Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint('callout:Google_API_Key'+strURL);
        request.setHeader('key', '{!$Credential.Password}');
        request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);         
        return http.send(request);

Comment: @Ajay The Google API needs the key in the query string, not in a header. The only way this would work is if the Google API supports `POST` with `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which I'm not sure it does. You may want to ask a new question for better support, as I can't write the needed code in a comment.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thank you, I just created a new question. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344555/named-credentials-google-api-key

Comment: How does $credential work, how does it merge in the correct named Credential?
Is it because you previously specified it in your setEndpoint('callout:jotform/user') method?
The documentation does not explain this setup: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm

Comment: @NZDev Yes, given the NC is called `jotform`, then `callout:jotform` tells Apex you want to use that specific NC, for which the `$Credential` merge fields will use for populating values. The `$variable` syntax denote  "global" variables that use their context to obtain data, such as `$Flow` and `$User`.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question because I wanted to find out what the best configuration was to make requests to an api that only uses a token in the header as the authentication protocol. The reason I did this research is because I wanted certainty about the correct secure method of storing the token.

This question and sfdcfox's answer were interesting, but with the release of next-generation Named Credentials in 2022, there is now a supported way.

I initially created a Named Credential with an External Credential and added a custom header with Name: . However, it was clear to me that this was not a Salesforce prescribed secure method.

This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5) confirmed my thoughts.

The correct method to store an API token or key for API request authentication in Salesforce is to *store the API Key as an Authentication Parameter in a Permission Set Mapping*