# Named Credentials - Google API Key

Tags: apex, rest-api, google-map

As google required to pass API key in the URL, I am trying to use Named Credentials, however, I am not how to figure out how to pass the key in the URL using a secure way.

Named Credentails:
[image]

I tried this:

```
Http http = new Http(); 
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
request.setMethod('GET'); 
request.setEndpoint('callout:Google_API_Key'+strURL); 
request.setHeader('key', '{!$Credential.Password}'); 
request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT); return http.send(request);
```

this doesn't work as it needs a key in the URL not in the header.

and also tried but no luck

```
request.setMethod('POST');        
request.setEndpoint('callout:Google_API_Key'+strURL);
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'key={!$Credential.Password}');
```

Any better way to secure the key and make the callout?

**Update**: Next attempt suggested by @sfdcfox

```
Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');        
        request.setEndpoint('callout:Google_API_Key'+strURL);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setBody(strUrl+'&key={!$Credential.Password}');
       
        request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);
```

return http.send(request);

**Endpoint:**

```
Endpoint=callout:Google_API_Key/directions/json?origin=903+Parkview+Drive%0D%0AA302%2C+King+of+Prussia%2C+PA%2C+19406&destination=1701+John+F+Kennedy+Blvd%2C+Philadelphia%2C+PA+19103&mode=DRIVING&arrival_time=1641996000&departure_time=1641992400&traffic_model=best_guess&, Method=POST
```

**ERROR:**

```
"error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
```

Comment: try adding header as request.setHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);

Comment: tried this way already, request.setHeader('key', '{!$Credential.Password}'); no luck

Comment: its 'x-api-key' not just 'key'

Comment: tried, I am getting "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps"

Comment: You have the correct key  and a Google account with billing information added right?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not possible using API key with named credentials as there is no way to inject the key in URL. Named credentials are built for Authentication and Authentication is for users, API keys are for projects - no principal/no user.

Most of the Google Maps API are URL based (all parameters in URL as query string)  and work with both GET and POST request which is why you don't get any other code apart from `200` OK when you switch HTTP verbs.

The reason you get `200` status code always is because your request is successfully processed and either resulted in an error or success.

So you will need to store this API key somewhere or Use another authentication method.

You cannot put the key in the URL in named credential (plain sight) as well because named credential name should be followed by a path. Adding `&` will add it to named credential's name.

Comment: yeah, you may be right, but I just wanted to explore options before I come to the conclusion that it is not possible. What do you recommend in this type of key stored securely in the system? Use encrypted field in an object and decrypt and send it in URL? or List Custom Settings or Custom Metadata? trying to find out how the world is doing in betterway.

Comment: Depending on who has access to setup. We do it as custom metadata and don't give users access to this metadata via profiles. in GCP config make sure that this key is only used for directions API.

Answer (score 0):

Google requires the key to be part of the query string, not a header. I'm not sure if the Google APIs support URL parameters as a body (most services do, but you never know if it's not documented). You can try the following:

```
request.setMethod('POST');        
request.setEndpoint('callout:Google_API_Key'+strURL);
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setBody(strUrl+'&key={!$Credential.Password}');
```

I presume that strURL should look something like:

```
origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood
```

Which means the entire body should look like:

```
origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=12345
```

You also need to check "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body" in order for this to even have a chance of working.

Comment: it seems to be that the key is not passed, it is getting errored out as attached. yes, I am passing both origin and destination in the URL, surprisingly the response status is "200", but still getting an error that an API key is required.

Comment: @Ajay If you're using the above suggestion, all query parameters should be in the body, just in case. But again, I'm not sure this is even supported (not all servers do), but I'll try and test this out this weekend.

Comment: I am trying this tomorrow, and also trying to see what other platforms are doing to make callout. Thank you

Comment: tried sending all the query parameters in the body, this time getting a 404 error.